# How do you get all X objects in all Y objects?

Tags: c#, excel, linq, vsto, ienumerable

I got a class named *Sheet*, with a List containing *Row* objects. Each Row object has a List containing *Cell* objects. Now I want to implement a *Sheet.Cells* property that returns all cells on all rows. I'm sure there must be an elegant LINQ solution for this, but haven't been able to figure it out. Assuming I got all rows in this.rows, how do I use LINQ to get an IEnumerable containing all cells in all rows?

```
IEnumerable<Cell> cells = this.rows ...?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is, called SelectMany:

```
IEnumerable<Cell> cells = this.rows.SelectMany(r => r.Cells);
```